# Let $X \sim P_1$, $Y \sim P_2$, can we find $f$ such that $f(X,Y) \sim P_1 P_2$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X \sim P_1$, $Y \sim P_2$ be two random variables with respective probability laws $P_1,P_2$.

We define $P(A)=P_1(A)P_2(A)$ for all $A$'s in the sigma algebra. $P$ is a probability law.

Can we find a function $f$ such that $f(X,Y)\sim P$ ?

Comment: $P$ defined as you have is not a probability measure as it is not additive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be disjoint. Then $$P(A \cup B) = P_1(A \cup B) P_2(A \cup B) = (P_1(A) + P_1(B))(P_2(A) +P_2(B)  = P(A) + P(B) + P_1(A)P_2(B) + P_2(A)P_1(B)$$

So, apart from some special cases, this is not a probability measure in general.

Comment: If we suppose that we are in those special cases, is it possible to answer the question ?

Comment: These special cases will only occur if your random variables $X,Y$ are not really 'random' in the sense that for each event $A$ it either holds $P_i(A) = 1$ or $P_i(A) =0$. Do you think you can answer your question now?